# jquery Getting percentage to increase div width

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I am stuck trying to figure out an equation for increasing div width based on the current height of the div.

## THE DETAILS

I have a div with an background image set to contain. The base background image is 640px wide and 900px high. The div has a min-height of 450px and width of 320px. When the div is clicked i want it to increase width to show the full background image.

If the div height is 450px do not extend div because the full background image width is currently shown. if the div height is 900px then the div width will extend double of current width(640px).

## THE PROBLEM

I'm having a hard time figuring out what value to increase the width of the div based on the current div height value to show the full background image. Can any one help me out with the correct equation?

Comment: Why can't you just hardcode the max width/height values?

Comment: The width and height increase by 50%, you can just times the width and height by 2.

Comment: because it is a dynamic expand / collapse section and the background image is set to contain

Comment: the issue is the in between values of 450 and 900px. so if the div height is 700px how much do i increase the width to show the full background.

Comment: I don't get the issue though, you would just subtract 700 from 900

Comment: One question, will the size of the background image always be 640x900?

Comment: the image itself will always be that size. But it will responsively scale itself depending on the height/width of the current window. I wrote a quick jsfiddle with my current situation: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vWxnM/8/) . You may notice after clicking on the div it may scale the bg image by both width and height. this is because the aspect ration of the div container is different then the  image. so the "cover" style will scale accordingly. this is what I don't want to happen and I am aware that my equation in the js code is incorrect. that is the part i'm trying to figure out.

Comment: How's this: http://jsfiddle.net/3jJv9/

Comment: Doesn't look like that did it. I'm sure the issue is in the jquery mathematics.

Comment: I was able to figure it out [link to jsfiddle]http://jsfiddle.net/vWxnM/14/ I had minHeight and Cur height on the wrong sides of the division math.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out [jsfiddle]http://jsfiddle.net/vWxnM/14 I had minHeight and Cur height on the wrong sides of the division math.

```
var scaleHeight = curHeight / minHeight;
```